# NewTX no longer prints ≗, ≖, blackboard bold (e.g., ), ⊛, Hebrew (say, ד) , ✓ properly

Tags: pdftex, dvips, newtxmath, newtx, dvi-mode

With the TeX Live 2023 as of 2023-08-13, upon running `latex` on

```latex
\documentclass{article}% version 2023/05/17 v1.4n. Same problem with standalone.
\usepackage{newtx}% version 2023/07/30 v1.723. Same problem with newtxtext, newtxmath.
\begin{document}
\({\circeq}, {\eqcirc}, \mathbb{B}, \mathbb{N}, \mathbb{Z}, \circledast, \daleth, \checkmark\), \checkmark
\end{document}
```

and then `xdvi` I got

[image: DVI output]

Instead of ד we see .

We get the same problem when running `pdflatex` on the LaTeX file:

[image: PDF output]

If we translate the DVI file via `dvips` to Postscript, we get

[image: PS output]

As you see, ALL symbols except the commas are wrong.

I ran `egrep -i "err|miss|warn|fail"` on the outputs of `latex`, `pdflatex`, `dvips`, and on the log file; no occurrences were reported.  So the typesetter is left blind about a whole bunch of symbols being misrepresented or absent.

Do you get the same or a similar issue? Who is the culprit and what to do? The NewTX maintainer has been informed.

Comment: the package merged two fonts in txsym.pfb.  The glyph numbers for \daleth and \Bbbk have been confused in newtxmath. The problem with dvips is that the map entry says `ntxsym ntxsym <txsym.pfb`  but it should be `ntxsym txsym <txsym.pfb` (the dvips route is much more picky about font names than pdftex).

Answer (score 2):

Fixed in NewTX v1.724, 2023/08/20, which is available in TeX Live 2023 as of 2023-08-23.